# How to union a hardcoded row after each grouped result

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image: what the resulting data set should look like]

After every group / row i want to insert a hardcoded dummy row with a bunch of 'xxxx' to act a separator.

I would like to use oracle sql to do this query. i can execute it using a loop but i don't want to use plsql.

Comment: This is really better done at the application layer.

Comment: this needs to be separated in this way to be downloaded as a csv and uploaded to another application as a summary file

Answer (score 1):

As the others suggest, it is best to do it on the front end.

However, if you have a *burning need* to be done as a query, here is how.
Here I did not use the rownum function as you have already done. I assume, your data is returned by a query, and you can replace my table with your query.
I made few more assumptions, as you have data with row numbers in it.
[I am not sure what do you mean by not PL/SQL]

```
Select Case When MOD(rownm, 2) = 0 then ' '
      Else to_char((rownm + 1) / 2) End as rownm,
      name, total, column1
From
(
select (rownm * 2 - 1) rownm,name, to_char(total) total ,column1 from t
union
SELECT (rownm * 2)  rownm,'XXX' name, 'XXX' total, 'The row act .... ' column1  FROM t
) Q
Order by Q.rownm;
```

and here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9fec68/6)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already grouping the data, it might be easier to use [`GROUPING SETS`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets#grouping_sets) instead of a `UNION`.

Grouping sets let you group by multiple sets of columns, including the same set twice to duplicate rows. Then the `GROUP_ID` function can be used to determine when the fake values should be used. This code will be a bit smaller than a `UNION` approach, and should be faster since it doesn't need to reference the table multiple times.

```
select
    case when group_id() = 0 then name            else ''   end name,
    case when group_id() = 0 then sum(some_value) else null end total,
    case when group_id() = 1 then 'this rows...'  else ''   end column1
from
(
    select 'jack'  name, 22 some_value from dual union all
    select 'jack'  name,  1 some_value from dual union all
    select 'john'  name, 44 some_value from dual union all
    select 'john'  name,  1 some_value from dual union all
    select 'harry' name,  1 some_value from dual union all
    select 'harry' name,  1 some_value from dual
) raw_data
group by grouping sets (name, name)
order by raw_data.name, group_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use row generator technique (using `CONNECT BY`) and then use `CASE..WHEN` as follows:

```
SQL> SELECT CASE WHEN L.LVL = 1 THEN T.ROWNM END AS ROWNM,
  2         CASE WHEN L.LVL = 1 THEN T.NAME
  3          ELSE 'XXX' END AS NAME,
  4         CASE WHEN L.LVL = 1 THEN TO_CHAR(T.TOTAL)
  5      ELSE 'XXX' END AS TOTAL,
  6         CASE WHEN L.LVL = 1 THEN T.COLUMN1
  7          ELSE 'This row act as separator..' END AS COLUMN1
  8    FROM T CROSS JOIN (
  9  SELECT LEVEL AS LVL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2
 10  ) L ORDER BY T.ROWNM, L.LVL;

     ROWNM NAME       TOTAL COLUMN1
---------- ---------- ----- ---------------------------
         1 Jack       23
           XXX        XXX   This row act as separator..
         2 John       45
           XXX        XXX   This row act as separator..
         3 harry      2
           XXX        XXX   This row act as separator..
         4 roy        45
           XXX        XXX   This row act as separator..
         5 Jacob      26
           XXX        XXX   This row act as separator..

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```